# How to call function from a TypeScript file in nodejs script?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm-scripts

I'm looking for a way to execute function on fly, without saving compiled `.js` file

I've tried `tsx` and `ts-node`, but they run the entire module, so logic has to be in a IIFE way:

```
(() => {
  // ...
})();
```

Running by script:

```
tsx <file_path>
```

Is there any way to make it from IIFE to named exported function and call it like:

```
tsExcecutor <file_path>/functionName
```

Comment: I would try `ts-node -c "require(file_path).functionName"`

Comment: @Konrad thx for your response, but this doen't work for me: "'functionName' is unexpected, on removing it - "Unknown or unexpected option: -c"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make a script obviously but don't know if you are asking to somehow make IIFE function named that's not possible I guess. But you can make an executor file with a passed function name to execute on the go like that.

```
const [, , command] = process.argv;
const [filePath, functionName] = command.split('/');
const modulePath = path.resolve(filePath);
const module = require(modulePath);

if (typeof module[functionName] === 'function') {
  const functionToExecute = module[functionName];
  (() => {
    functionToExecute();
  })();
} else {
  console.error(`Function '${functionName}' not found in '${filePath}'.`);
}
```

and then from command line.

```
ts-node tsExecutor.ts ./example.ts/myFunction
```

Comment: thx for answer, you did greate propose for process.argv, they just went out of my mind, thx you

Answer (score 1):

You may make a script

```json
// package.json: 
{
  "scripts": {
    "tsr": "tsx -e \"let[,m,f,...a]=process.argv;console.log(require(m)[f](...a))\"",
    "mul": "npm run tsr ./math mul 23 45"
  }
}
```

which will run

```
// `tsx --eval` the below code:
const [_node, moduleName, fnName, ...args] = process.argv;
// 'node.exe' './math'    'mul'   ['23','45]
const module = require(moduleName)
const fn = module[fnName];
const result = fn(...args)
console.log(result)
```

(provided with)

```
// math.ts
export function mul(a: string, b: string) { return +a * +b }
```

You may use it as `npm run tsr ./math mul 23 45` from command line